# Making requests from Netlify app (https) to a server without SSL (http)

Tags: http, web, https

I have a React project hosted as a Netlify subdomain, and on the other hand I have a backend in a virtual environment that does not have an SSL certificate. I need to connect my React project to my Backend but when making a request I get the following message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7kIR.png)

After some research, I saw that I can solve this with a Proxy, an HTTPS to HTTP adapter, but I really don't know how to use either of them. The other way I found is by using an SSL certificate on the backend, but for that I need to have a domain name (the virtual environment only gives me an IP address), and I don't have the money to buy a domain at this time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198). Also, can you not host the backend in the same subdomain as the UI?

Comment: I don't think I can do it.  However, I managed to host the backend on another subdomain that does offer me an SSL certificate and I have already managed to solve that issue.